# jQuery UI Combobox: How can I add a class to autocomplete div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I use the jQuery combobox plugin:

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

My JS:

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  });
```

My goal is to add a custom class to the autocomplete div in order to individually style the autocomplete dropdown. I already tried the following, but this is not working:

```
$( "#combobox" ).combobox().autocomplete("widget").addClass('my-custom-autocomplete-class');
```

Comment: If you inspect the dropdown you can see that it already has a class named `ui-autocomplete`

Comment: The autocomplete widget is bound against an `input` appended an inserted `span`. You can get it using `$("#combobox").next("span").find("input")`. Of course, you could also go the none-insane-way and use the appropriate selector `$(".custom-combobox-input")`

Comment: @theblackgigant I know! My goal is to give it an extra custom class.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, As per selected value class add to combobox write css for each option mention in drop down

```
$(function($) {
$( 'select[id=combobox]' ).on("change",function() {
  var dynaminClass = $(this).val();
  console.log(dynaminClass);  
  $(this).attr('class', dynaminClass);

})
```

})